# Using ffill and bfill based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to ffill and bfill based on a certain condition for my dataframe.
Basically for entries that have the same row below of `['SCU_KEY', 'PRODUCT', 'REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG']`, then I would like to front fill (ffill) the 'START_DATE' until it no longer shares all 3 column conditions.
The bfill will be the same but for all rows above and instead of 'START_DATE' it will be 'END_DATE'.
Since the code will obviously be about the same, we can ignore the 'END_DATE' code to avoid the unnecessary effort.
I attached an image of some data and for the record I would like the 'START_DATE' for first row: '2020-06-30' (index #1041) to be the same for next row (which shows '2018-02-24').
Another example could be shown starting at index #1593 with START_DATE '2020-11-02' and for that number to be "ffill"ed until index #1769 to replace all entries until you see '2018-05-01'.
Here is my code that is an unfinished attempt:

[image]

```py
cond18 = df_5['SCU_KEY'] == df_5['SCU_KEY'].shift(-1)
cond19 = df_5['PRODUCT'] == df_5['SCU_KEY'].shift(-1)
cond20 = df_5['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'] == df_5['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'].shift(-1)
df_5['START_DATE'].ffill() = np.where((cond18) & (cond19) & (cond20), df_5['START_DATE'], df_5['START_DATE'].shift(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
(df
  .groupby(['SCU_KEY', 'PRODUCT', 'REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'])
  .apply(lambda x: x.assign(START_DATE = lambda x: x['START_DATE'].ffill()))
  .reset_index()
  .groupby(['SCU_KEY', 'PRODUCT', 'REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'])
  .apply(lambda x: x.assign(END_DATE = lambda x: x['END_DATE'].bfill()))
  .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. It does return without an error message but not getting the results I want. I can't see how it could solve the issue if it doesn't create a condition for filling when there are simultaneous values for 3 column values. Maybe the part that you got tripped up or that I didn't explain fully is that the revenue_status_flag will switch from 1 to 0 and vise versa with the sort that I have. So a code that will get the simultaneous 1s or the simultaneous 0s from the same product and scu_key on the chart

Comment: I think something that could better describe in code what I am looking for but I get an error returning would be if it was: ``` (df
  .groupby(['SCU_KEY', 'PRODUCT', 'REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'])
  .apply(lambda x: x.assign(START_DATE = lambda x: x['START_DATE'].ffill() if x['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'] == x['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'].shift(-1)) ```